# Gnu Octave build error under MinGW/MSYS

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, mingw, octave

I'm trying to build Gnu Octave for Windows.I built all the main dependencies without having much problem.And configuring process went well.But when I tried to run `make`(After few source modifications to get over some errors),It triggers tons of errors like

```
./.libs/liboctinterp.a(liboctinterp_la-octave.o): In function `safe_source_file':
C:\MinGW\sources\octave-3.6.2\src/octave.cc:312: undefined reference to `___cxa_begin_catch'
```

At the line

```
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -pthread -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -mieee-fp -Wall -W -Wshadow -Wformat -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -g -O2 -pthread -pthread -g -O2 -pthread -o .libs/octave.exe main.o  ./.libs/liboctinterp.a /mingw/sources/octave-3.6.2~~/liboctave/.libs/liboctave.a -L=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0 -L=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -L=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -L=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../.. -lfltk_gl -lfltk -lole32 -luuid -lcomctl32 -LC:/MinGW/lib /mingw/lib/libfontconfig.dll.a -L=C:/MinGW/lib /mingw/lib/libfreetype.dll.a -lz -lbz2 /mingw/lib/libexpat.dll.a -lopengl32 -lglu32 ../liboctave/.libs/liboctave.a /mingw/sources/octave-3.6.2~~/libcruft/.libs/libcruft.a /mingw/lib/libarpack.a /mingw/lib/libfftw3.a -lreadline -ltermcap /mingw/lib/libpcre.dll.a ../libcruft/.libs/libcruft.a -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lquadmath -liberty -lgdi32 -lws2_32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -pthread -L/mingw/lib
```

I dumped the make log to a file and the file is about 39MB!! Just full of errors like above.
I'm very much thankful if someone can help me to get over this.

Comment: Which version of Octave did you download?  Are you following a guide on how to install Octave from source on windows, like this:  http://octave.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/octave/trunk/octave-forge/admin/Windows/mingw32/HOWTO.txt or are you winging it?

Comment: @EricLeschinski I'm trying to build it octave-3.6.2 source distribution here ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave yes I tried that,I even tried this http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/octave/Eng/Win/Readme_octave-3.6.0.txt
But no luck yet.It triggers an error either n this status or sysdep.cc

Comment: It's possible that the latest version of octave requires a linux kernel that has features which yours do not provide.  What is your version of MinGW?  Maybe try blowing it away and getting the latest version?  Maybe you could try installing an older version of Octave like maybe 3.4.3.  Maybe try using cygwin instead of MinGW?

Comment: MinGW installation is not much old,Just a month or two.So it's practically the newest version.GCC version is 4.7.0 In here http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/octave/Eng/Win/ ,He says octave 3.6.0 can be compiled with MinGW.I tried that version to and didn't work for me.I'm planning to use cygwin but the problem is then I can't make stand alone binary.